# Is there a way to upload animated gif using facebook api? PHP

Tags: php, facebook, gif

Stack is using Php Laravel.

Currently tried to use graph api page_id/photos to post an animated gif. But when it got posted to facebook page, it became a still image.

Any advice on whether there are facebook API to upload animated gif to a page?

Or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks.